# How to get current LayoutAwarePage?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm not asking about the Type of the current LayoutAwarePage

```
Type type = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).CurrentSourcePageType;
```

but about instance of current Page, I need an access to its properties

Comment: Type t = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).GetType() would get you the Type for the Content current Window. But, then you'd need to use Reflection to gain access to the properties. Is that what you'd want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
var page = (LayoutAwarePage)frame.Content;
```

Comment: You could use dynamic of course but I think it is not recommended unless you are working with COM, DOM, reflection, dynamic languages or some such things.
"As a developer, you use the dynamic keyword with variables expected to contain objects of uncertain type such as objects returned from a COM or DOM API; obtained from a dynamic language (IronRuby, for example); from reflection; from objects built dynamically in C# 4.0 using the new expand capabilities." - from this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336309.aspx).

Comment: In this case you should just cast it to the type of your page insted to `LayoutAwarePage`. This way you can still avoid using `dynamic`.